# Можно ли кастить long/double во float? Или long в double C#?

Tags: c#, json, типы-данных

Получаю json по api преобразовываю в структуру, но там получается вложенные массивы и нужно это переконвертить в нужный мне класс. Но данные приходят иногда double иногда long. И не получается привести к общему типу пробывал и float и double. Сейчас оставил float так как в доке к API описано что должны быть float, но json парсер их определяет как double. Вот дока навсякий https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html.
Вот скрин структурки, там выделил одно и тоже поле. Оно бывает double бывает long.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это класс, что бы он знал как конвертить json

```
public class AirData
    {
            public string icao24;
            public string callsign;
            public string origin_country;
            public long time_position;
            public long last_contact;
            public float longitude;
            public float latitude;
            public float baro_altitude;
            public bool on_ground;
            public float velocity;
            public float true_track;
            public float vertical_rate;
            public object sensors;
            public float geo_altitude;
            public string squawk;
            public bool spi;
            public long position_source;   
    }
```

Это метод где пытаюсь приводить типы как нужно

```
public List<AirData> ConvertToAirData()
        {
            var temp = new List<AirData>();
            foreach (var notformatted in states)
            {
                var airData = new AirData();
                airData.icao24 = (string) notformatted[0];
                airData.callsign = (string) notformatted[1];
                airData.origin_country = (string) notformatted[2];
                airData.time_position = (long) notformatted[3];
                airData.last_contact = (long) notformatted[4];
                airData.longitude = (float) notformatted[5];
                airData.latitude = (float) notformatted[6];
                airData.baro_altitude = (float) notformatted[7];
                airData.on_ground = (bool) notformatted[8];
                airData.velocity = (float) notformatted[9];
                airData.true_track = (float) notformatted[10];
                airData.vertical_rate = (float) notformatted[11];
                airData.sensors = notformatted[12];
                airData.geo_altitude = (float) notformatted[13];
                airData.squawk = (string) notformatted[14];
                airData.spi = (bool) notformatted[15];
                airData.position_source = (long) notformatted[16];
                temp.Add(airData);
            }
            return temp;
        }
```

Выдает постоянно ошибки о не правильном приведении типа.
"Необработанное исключение: System.InvalidCastException: Заданное приведение является недопустимым.
"
Проблема вроде решилась, как писал в комментах.
Вот код как получаю json может кому будет полезно.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebRequest request =
            WebRequest.Create("https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?lamin=51.421812&lomin=23.139124&lamax=55.961184&lomax=33.472494");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Answer answer;
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string fullJson = "";
                    string line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        fullJson += line;
                    }

                    // Console.WriteLine(fullJson);
                    try
                    {
                        var res = new List<AirData>();
                        answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Answer>(fullJson);
                        res = answer.ConvertToAirData();
                        foreach (var VARIABLE in res)
                      {
                       Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE);     
                        }

                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ничего нету");
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }

            response.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Запрос выполнен");
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: Попробуйте `Convert.ToInt64();` для long. Для остальных типов Convert тоже подходит.

Comment: `float` и `long` всегда можно [конвертировать](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table) в `double`. Обратное неверно. Поэтому укажите `double` - оно годится в обоих показанных вами случаях. Хотя, конечно, может быть потеря точности.

Comment: а не пробовали использовать тип `dynamic`? Либо вообще скатывать все к `object`?

Comment: В документации написано `float` - это означает _вещественное_ число (т. е. `long` отпадает), но не указана его точность (может и указана, надо всю доку прошерстить). Это в C# есть `float` (32 бит) и `double` (64 бит). В других языках `float` может означать 64 бит.

Comment: Уже пробовал все вещественные числа объявить как double. Вот сейчас еще раз попробовал что бы убедится. В этой строке выдает ошибку  airData.vertical_rate = (double) notformatted[11]; Захожу в дебагер что бы посмотреть какой тип подается на вход ему и там long ( [11] = {long}0).

Comment: Еще пойду тестить но вроде как замена (double)  на Convert.ToDouble() решило проблему

Comment: Вы не показали главное: как вы получаете этот json и десериализуете его?

Comment: Добавил код , как получаю и десериализую json. Может кто попутно расскажет в чем разница (double) и Convert.ToDouble(). И может еще Convert.ToSingle() - предлагали  как еще один вариант решения.

Comment: Почему вы привели огрызок кода? Его невозможно скопировать и выполнить. Вы не привели самое главное: класс `Answer`. А именно в нём самая мякотка: ведь в него десериализуются данные. (Хотя, конечно, восстановить его несложно).

Comment: После десериализации вы получаете массивы `object[]`. Соответственно, данные внутри них являются изначально `object`. Поэтому приведение (каст) невозможен. Десериализовать сразу в нужный тип тоже нельзя, т. к. сам json не содержит необходимой информации - это просто массив смешанных данных. Поэтому используйте методы `Convert.To*`.